# What to call a list of banknote + quantity

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When transfering cash, especially with large sums or in cashier/accounting jobs you are often tasked with filling and/or signing a piece of paper that is essentially a list of nominal values their quantities which could look like following:

```
| Value | Quantity |
| ------| -------- |
|     1 |      137 |
|     2 |      102 |
|     5 |      51  |
....
total $ 596
```

What is this list (piece of paper) called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a name specific to banking, partly because I have always seen this list on the back of a 'paying-in slip'.

It is similar in nature to an inventory, tally, log or a breakdown.